# Decorating a class method

Tags: python, class, decorator

I want to decorate a class method, but can't quite figure out how to do it. Minimal class example:

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.R = radius

    def arc_length(self,theta):
        return self.R*theta
```

Now let's say I want another method which takes the arc_length always relative to some particular other value of arc length so I define a function as follows:

```
def relative(rel_val):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args):
            return fn(*args) - fn(rel_val)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

so now I extend my class to:

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.R = radius

    def arc_length(self,theta):
        return self.R*theta

    @relative(0.2)
    def relative_arc_length(self,theta):
        return self.arc_length(theta)
```

I would hope this would give the desired behaviour, but I get error:
     relative_arc_length() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

I assume this is something to do with the self argument, but if I add self to the fn(self,rel_val) in the relative definition it gives me: global name "self" is not defined

So how do I fix this? Interestingly, if I do the following:

```
c = Circle(10)
relative(0.2)(c.arc_length)(1.5)
```

it works as expected.

Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong? Also, is it possible to define the decorated function inside the class, and if so, should I do this? Is it good programming practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return fn(*args) - fn(rel_val)
```

Methods are always called with `self` as the first parameter. So in your case, you are passing all arguments just fine to the first call, but forget the `self` in the second call.

You will have to extract `self` from `args` and pass that too:

```
obj, value = args
return fn(obj, value) - fn(obj, rel_value)
```

You should probably include a check to ensure that there are only exactly two values in `args` at any time too, so you don’t accidentally use the decorator for incompatible methods.

Comment: Great answer. It took me some time to realize that there was nothing wrong with writing `fn(*args)` in the return statement (rewriting it to `fn(obj, value)` makes no difference); the error came from `fn(rel_val)` as this was missing the underlying object as the first parameter